# How to Hide .smarty-ui on International address

Tags: javascript, smartystreets

I really needed help here with the smarty street, on my form i have section Physical address and Mailing address both address can be domestic or International address, I try to hide the smarty-ui if address International address example on the Physical address is Domestic  address and on the Mailing address is International address, as on the images if the International check i will set $(".smarty-ui").hide();  when i clicked save button the  smarty-ui popup still display on the international address.

Thanks in advance for all the

here is my example

```
var isPhysicalIntChecked = $("input[id='Address1_isInternational']:checked").length;
        var isPhysicalMailingIntChecked = $("input[id='Address2_isInternational']:checked").length;
        if (isPhysicalIntChecked ==0) {
            var ss = enableSmartyStreets();
            attachSSEventHandler(ss);
            $(".smarty-ui").show();
        }
        else $(".smarty-ui").hide();
        if (isPhysicalMailingIntChecked == 0) {
            var ss = enableSmartyStreets();
            attachSSEventHandler(ss);
            $(".smarty-ui").show();
        }
        else $(".smarty-ui").hide();

function enableSmartyStreets() {
        debugger;
        var liveaddress = $.LiveAddress(
        {
            key: '@ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmartyStreetsHTMLKey"]',
            debug: false,
            submitSelector: '#btnSave',
            addresses: [
                {
                    id: 'physical',
                    street: '#Address1_street1',
                    street2: '#Address1_street2',
                    city: '#Address1_city',
                    state: '#Address1_stateAndTerritoriesId',
                    zipcode: '#Address1_zipCode5'
                },
                {
                    id: 'mailing',
                    street: '#Address2_street1',
                    street2: '#Address2_street2',
                    city: '#Address2_city',
                    state: '#Address2_stateAndTerritoriesId',
                    zipcode: '#Address2_zipCode5'
                }
            ]
        });
        return liveaddress;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you map a country input field to the plugin it will automatically hide the smarty-ui when the country is not `US`, `United States`, or another common identifier. You can see an example of how this works [here](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugin/examples#country). You would have to remove your checkbox and just use a country input field instead.